# window.onscroll not working with parallax effect

Tags: javascript

I'm confused, I've been trying to use a `onscroll` function to get a value for`scrollTop`. In an `onload` function it worked and returned 0 to the console, but with `onscroll` I get nothing. Tried it in codepen (https://codepen.io/dillonbrannick/pen/LqvzeR) and the console returns exactly as it should, not sure why on my web page's the console isn't returning anything for the exact same function.

The function in question:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    var y = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    console.log(y);
};
```

As Tyler pointed out in the comments the problem is due to the parallax effect, so I've updated the question to reflect this. The parralax effect was built off of Keith Clark's Parallax code (https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites).

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
    var y = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    console.log(y);
};
```

```css
body{
height:100%;
  margin: 0px 0 0px 0;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
  transform-origin-x: 100%;
}
.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin-x: 100%;
}
.parallax__layer--base {
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.parallax__layer--back_01 {
  transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(8);
}

.bg {
  position:relative;
  left:100px;
  top:200px;
height:100px;
width:100px;
background-color:red;
}
p {
  background-color:blue;
  height:250px;
  color:white;
}
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
 width:80%;
 max-width:960px;
 margin:0 auto 0 auto;
 height: auto;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.more{
  margin-top:200px;
    position:relative;
    
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parallax">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back_01">
      <div class="bg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <p>content</p>
        <p class="more">More</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: If I had to guess,  it has something to do with the implementation of the parallax; you're not actually scrolling the `window`, but rather a container (`<body>` or otherwise). If you scroll around and run your code in console at different points ( `document.documentElement.scrollTop;`), you'll notice the result is *always* `0` regardless of where you've scrolled to.

Comment: Confirming the above: When attaching the `onscroll` event to your `<div class="paralax">` instead of the `window` element, the event fires as you're expecting. That said, the result is still `0` simply because you're getting the `scrollTop` of `documentElement`, which as explained, isn't actually scrolling at all.

Comment: And for the comment hattrick: Please note that, while I've hopefully helped you solve the issue, I haven't submitted an answer because this question is *off-topic*. It relies on external resources to provide any sort of answer, and the problem is not replicated in the question itself. If your website ever goes down or changes in the future, this question is *useless* to future readers.

Comment: @TylerRoper I can edit the question to include the parallax code and change it to "How do you get oncroll function to work with parallax?"

Comment: Good idea. I believe something like that would certainly improve the question. You can use inline stack snippets (the button to the right of the *Image* button when editing your question) to include a full, runnable example in the question itself.

Comment: @TylerRoper okay I'll do that, I can tag you back once it's done and you can re-add your answer if you want, I saw it, and it worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Not a problem - that answer was actually by someone else (Asaf Aviv), so I'll give him a chance to add his answer back. Unfortunately he cannot be tagged in this comment section because he hasn't participated in it.

Comment: @TylerRoper ah that's unfortunate, I've updated the question there anyway, sure you can answer or I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page implements a container element (`<div class="parallax">`) that houses the contents. **This** element is the one that is scrolling up and down, not the `window` itself.

```js
document.querySelector('.parallax').addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  console.log(this.scrollTop);
});
```

```css
body{
height:100%;
  margin: 0px 0 0px 0;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
  transform-origin-x: 100%;
}
.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin-x: 100%;
}
.parallax__layer--base {
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.parallax__layer--back_01 {
  transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(8);
}

.bg {
  position:relative;
  left:100px;
  top:200px;
height:100px;
width:100px;
background-color:red;
}
p {
  background-color:blue;
  height:250px;
  color:white;
}
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
 width:80%;
 max-width:960px;
 margin:0 auto 0 auto;
 height: auto;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.more{
  margin-top:200px;
    position:relative;
    
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parallax">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back_01">
      <div class="bg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <p>content</p>
        <p class="more">More</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/discussions/1333

Parallax needs a hack solution to track scroll position since it is internal data.

One page of Parallax scroll in `@react-spring` = 529.5 scrollTop

```
export const parallaxScrollToOffset = (scrollY: number): number => {
  return scrollY / 529.5;
};

export const useParallaxScroll = (): number => {
  const [scroll, setScroll] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document
      .querySelector(".parallax")
      ?.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
        // @ts-ignore
        const { scrollTop } = this;
        setScroll(parallaxScrollToOffset(scrollTop));
      });
  }, []);

  return scroll;
};
```

In the App where you init the Parallax component you need to pass in a class name "parallax" so that the `useScrollPosition` can find it via the query selector.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Parallax
      className="parallax" // this makes `useScrollPosition` work
      pages={10} // arbitrary number, doesn't matter
    >
     {/* whatever else you want in the app */}
    </Parallax>
  );
};
```